# Panel in grid causes horizontal overflow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstraps grid system and inside that I use their panels. I have two `cols` and in each col I have one panel. But this creates a horizontal scrollbar on my page.

I could probably disable the horizontal overflow. But I'd rather "fix" the problem in a cleaner way that Bootstrap is causing.

What would be a good way to solve this problem?

Example: http://www.bootply.com/iPdjlxuexk

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Form widgets</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Panel content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Selected page widgets</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Panel content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I wrap a `<div class="container"></div>` around the `row` div, then the panels inside are really small. A big `margin-left` and `margin-right` apprears on the `container`. Not really what I'm after either.

http://www.bootply.com/BWMTAFeO8x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is occurring because of the following HTML class:

```
col-md-6
```

Specifically, with Bootstrap, this means that whatever is currently in this column will extend to be 6 column spaces wide. This is not good if you are looking to only have something, let's say, 3 column spaces wide because it actually stretches what you are trying to do.

**How do we fix it?**

Use a smaller width space and then use Bootstraps ability to push/pull things. I will demonstrate what I mean via a JsFiddle, which is found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ukns4/1/).

Basically, I altered your HTML to become the following:

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-lg-push-3 col-md-push-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Form widgets</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-lg-push-3 col-md-push-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Selected page widgets</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Panel content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**NOTE**

In my demonstration, I added the ability to view the panels in both a large screen setting and a medium screen setting versus just having it in a medium setting. I also had to push the columns according to the screen sizes. You can see this in effect with the JSFiddle by changing the width of the portion of the output screen in the demo. This is useful because you can see the difference between a large/medium sized screen to a small/extra-small sized screen.

**More Information:**

You can find more information on the grid system via the actual website. It will show you how the grid system is laid out and how you can use the push/pull aspect as well.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/